# Is it possible to initialize a data frame with both named and unnamed columns?

Tags: r, dataframe

Is it possible to create a data frame with one column named while the other is not? This one does not work:

```
 df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1, 2), c(1, 2))
> colnames(df)
[1] "col1"    "c.1..2."
```

Of coure, I could fix it with `colnames(df)[2] <- ""` afterwards, but my question is if it is possible to initialize an unnamed column.

Comment: Columns are supposed to have names. That is part of the data.frame framework.

Comment: Your comment suggests that it is not possible to have a data frame with an unnamed column, but that is wrong as I have shown above.

Comment: False. My comment suggests that it is inadvisable and the authors of the software discourage this as is seen in the difficulty of creating such a column with the use of the initiation function `data.frame`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass `fix.empty.names = FALSE` to the constructor:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(1, 2), c(1, 2), fix.empty.names=FALSE)
# > colnames(df)
# [1] "col1" ""
```